# Buying maximum items with limited money

Tags: c++, logic

So I have to solve a problem which asks us to find maximum unique items that can be bought with a given amount of money.So I input the number of items and the money that I possess .This is the code that I am using and it only provides solution for handful of cases while failing others.Don't have the access to test cases though.

What condition will fail this?Any ideas?

example:

```
Input:  7 50
        1 12 5 111 200 100 10

Output: 4



 int main()
    {
        int n,x,money,count=0,j=0;

        cout<<"Enter no of items and money you have";
        cin>>n>>money;        //size of array(number of items)
        vector<int> a(n);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cin>>x;           //assigning price of each item
            a[i]=x;
        }

        sort(a.begin(),a.end());  // sorting prices in ascending order

        while(money-a[j]>0)      //buying stuff until you are broke
        {
            j++;
            count++;
        }

        cout<<count;           //returning no of items that can be purchased.

    }
```

Comment: What's an example of a failing case for this algorithm?

Comment: Suppose you have 50 quids and the items with the following prices: 25, 24,5,3,2. Your algorithm will give 2, but in fact we can buy up to 4 items here.

Comment: @Kyle Strand Sadly I don't have access to them which is why I posted it here.

Comment: @Ashalynd If you look carefully the elements are first sortedand then deducted.

Comment: Are all items in the output supposed to have unique prices? Ah wait... it's much easier. You don't update the money after you subtract the value.

Comment: @Ashalynd Oh shit. Yeah!!How did I miss that?Feeling so dumb and embarrassed right now.But thank you so much and I shouldn't be solving problems at 4 in the morning.